# Scheduled task copying problems - no errors

Tags: cmd, copy, scheduled-tasks, network-drive

I am building a script that will do database backup and will copy the backup to a safe storage location on another computer. I have that specific location already mounted on Y: and have built my script (.bat).
The script runs fine in test runs, but when task scheduler runs it the part in charge of copying:

```
copy /Y "C:\something or other\Backup.bak" "Y:\DB\DB-%mydate%.bak"
```

doesn't run. In order to see what is going on when scheduler runs the script I appended

`>> backup.log`

to every line of the script.
When I tried manually running the scrip through task scheduler in order to test what is the problem the only thing copy outputs is:

```
0 file(s) copied
```

and nothing else. No other error.

I know that Start Folder set in task could be the problem but I did set it to the folder where the script is. Also start folder shouldn't be an issue since all the time I'm working with full paths.

**EDIT**: I'm running this on Windows Server 2003 SP2 if it has anything to do with it.

So any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: does your task run under the same account as the one which has the mapped drive ?

Comment: I have given the task scheduler the username and password of the computer Admin. They are probably correct since without a suitable login the script would fail when it attempts to connect to the DB in order to execute BACKUP command. Also wouldn't copy have outputted an error like "Location unreachable" or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to map the network drive inside the script or use UNC ?
something like

```
pushd \\server\path
copy c:\backup.bak .
popd
```

Comment: WTF? I first tried adding net use command in batch to check if it could see network drives and batch can see them, than as a test I added code to delete the networke drive and reconnect to it. And look at that it worked. BUT I then removed that code and in still works. WTF?!? Still I'm marking this as answer if people look at my comment.

Comment: I can  only think of different user beetween interactive and scheduled session...

Comment: Same user, but I think scheduled tasks get assigned a different session.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I have recently done some work with Windows server Scheduled tasks.

The exit code may help you if you look at the task scheduler highlight your task and select the history tab 0x0 is success 0x1 is some kind of error but not very specific...

Some basic pointers

- You can test the scheduled task by right clicking and selecting run
- The user account the task is running as requires logon as batch user
  permissions on the server you intend to run the task on this can be
  added to local policy start> run/search gpedit.msc or by
  administering group policy on the domain.
- If it is not the account you are using to test shift+right click command prompt and run as the user running the  task then run your batch file this will at least give you confidence the user account can run the batch file interactively

for more information see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721846.aspx

Comment: It reports 0x1 as error I guess.
I have tried running it by right clicking the task and selecting run. That is how I tested it and found out the copy operation was behaving wierdly.
I'm using the computer Admin account to run the script, the scheduler has been provided with username and password and it connects to DB and runs BACKUP command succesfully, it is logging on with no problems
I have tested the command while logged in as Admin.

Comment: Have you checke dthe admin user has logon as batch user access in group policy?

Comment: Wouldn't that completly prevent me from running any of the commands in the batch file? Because that is not what is happening. Only one line (copy) is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when trying to access/copy files from a protected network share via a Scheduled Task.

My problem was with the Scheduled Task's configuration.  Using Win10, my Task was configured as follows (under "General" - "Security options"):

- [ ] "Run only when user is logged on"
- [x] "Run whether user is logged on or not"

  - [x] "Do not store password.  The task will only have access to local resources"  *[This is the problem]*

I fixed the problem by un-checking the "Do not store password" checkbox.
Presumably, I could also fix it by opting for "Run only when user is logged on".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  After more research and testing, I solved it via the following in my .bat file, using net use.
Helpful sites:
https://www.lifewire.com/net-use-command-2618096
https://lazyadmin.nl/it/net-use-delete/

---

First mount the shared folder.
net use z: \MyOtherServer\TheSharedFolder

Do the copy and specify the full path to the files.
copy D:\MyLocalFolder\active\File1.txt z:\TheDestinationFolder\active\

Delete the newly mounted drive. 
/yes provides the confirmation answer to the prompt that comes up.
net use z: /delete /yes